# Making existing Visualforce pages to lightning ready before submitting to app exchange??St

Tags: appexchange, mobile, lightning-ready

We have developed our apps in Salesforce classic but as per the recent rule, that after march 1st Apps that aren't Lightning Ready will not be allowed to list in App Exchange. we have just added the styles SLDS Design Systems to our visualforce pages like this and few more..

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS213, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
```

Is this enough?
We couldn't apply styles for page block table..converting page block table to data table coflicts the jquery plugin associated with our existing visualforce pages?Should we make sure its responsive in mobile too?or just adding the above style is just enough to list in app Exchange?

Need Suggestions.Because we are almost nearing our security review stage.

Comment: You listed the main things to check: Design (Mobile VS Desktop display, original proportions kept, etc...) and the potential Javascript conflicts that can occur when embedding the VFP into a component into a Lightning application. Chrome offers a mobile devices simulator in the development tools.

Comment: Hi @Answers_Seeker it is better to help her with some links to documentation or blogs. Thanks